# Java 8 - Static Method Reference Rule

Tags: java-8

I have the following piece of code:

```
public class Chap20 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] names = { "John", "Jane" };
        Stream<String> namesStream = Stream.of(names);

        Path path = Paths.get(".");
        Stream<Path> files;
        try {
            files = Files.list(path);
            files.forEach(System.out::println);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Now here´s the file.forEach method signature:

```
void java.util.stream.Stream.forEach(Consumer<? super Path> action)
```

I´m reading it as a method that accepts a consumer of a type which is at least a Path type or a superclass of Path, but I´m probably missreading it, since System.out is not a superclass of Path.

Can someone please explain how to correct read it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`? super Path` says: 'It has to be a super class of Path.

`System.out.println` accepts an `Object`. `Object` is a super class of `Path` hence this is correct.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-java.lang.Object- There are several overloaded `println`. The compiler chooses the one that best applies. In this case the one that receives an `Object`.

Comment: ups! my bad, I thought that it's a `Stream<String>` there... but it's `Stream<Path>`

Comment: That was a very concise explanation and made me realize that i was considering the `System.out` type and not `System.out.println` parameter type as for beeing a super of Path. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are reading that entirely correct IMO, you are just mislead by the `::` notation probably. And it's not about `System.out` being a `Path` or not - it's about the *implied* parameter `x` (for example) that you can't see because of the method reference (read further).

There are a couple of things here, first one is called [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java); that is why the declaration is `? super P_OUT` or `? super Path`. Basically that means you can read any super type of `Path`. The only safe one would be `Object` (or any sub type of that, but you just don't know which exactly).

To make it simpler, you can write it like this for example:

```
Stream.of("John", "Jane")
            .forEach((Object x) -> System.out.println(x)); // Object
```

Or since the compiler can see (infer) the type to be `String` :

```
Stream.of("John", "Jane")
            .forEach((String x) -> System.out.println(x));  // String
```

Or you can omit that declaration at all and let the compiler do it's job:

```
Stream.of("John", "Jane")
            .forEach(/* this is infered as String here */ x -> System.out.println(x));
```

Now the second part is called a [Method Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).

Instead of writing:

```
 Stream.of("John", "Jane")
            .forEach(x -> System.out.println(x));
```

You could write it simpler:

```
 Stream.of("John", "Jane")
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

The `x` parameter (which is of type `? super T`) is implied here.

Comment: hey, you misread the OP's question. the answer is simple, because anything is `Object` and [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) stating that super type can be replaced with its sub types. and method reference expression `System.out::println` will be adapt to the target type `Consumer<? super Path>`, so the `println(Object)` win. but for your long explaination, encouragement +1, :)

Answer (score 1):

The method signature indicates the [forEach](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) method of [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) takes a Consumer, which consumes each element from the Stream upon which it is iterating, in your case a collection of Paths.

[Consumer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) refers to a [functional interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html) that accepts an input and returns no result. It is one of [many](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) implemented in Java 8 to work with [Lambdas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#approach6) and [method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html). A functional interface contains exactly one abstract method, also called its *functional method*.

The *forEach* method is used for iterating over a collection and applying an operation on each element. The operation, or "behavior" (any class implementing the Consumer interface), that's passed is the *action*, or lambda, performed on each element of the collection.

The [forEach](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) is an API (also added with Java 8) in the [Iterable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) interface, which "*performs the given action for each element of the Iterable until all elements have been processed or the action throws an exception*". It differs from the Java *for loop* in that it is an internal iterator, rather than an external one.